# Android crash in onCreate

Tags: android, eclipse, crash, nullpointerexception, logcat

Whenever I run my app, the first time I run it from Eclipse it runs fine. But then if I close the app and reopen it it will crash on onCreate. Here is the LogCat:

```
10-10 02:50:00.665: E/AndroidRuntime(29564): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-10 02:50:00.665: E/AndroidRuntime(29564): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.appuccino.unitconverter/com.appuccino.unitconverter.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-10 02:50:00.665: E/AndroidRuntime(29564):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
10-10 02:50:00.665: E/AndroidRuntime(29564):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
10-10 02:50:00.665: E/AndroidRuntime(29564):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
10-10 02:50:00.665: E/AndroidRuntime(29564):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
10-10 02:50:00.665: E/AndroidRuntime(29564):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-10 02:50:00.665: E/AndroidRuntime(29564):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-10 02:50:00.665: E/AndroidRuntime(29564):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
10-10 02:50:00.665: E/AndroidRuntime(29564):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-10 02:50:00.665: E/AndroidRuntime(29564):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-10 02:50:00.665: E/AndroidRuntime(29564):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
10-10 02:50:00.665: E/AndroidRuntime(29564):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
10-10 02:50:00.665: E/AndroidRuntime(29564):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-10 02:50:00.665: E/AndroidRuntime(29564): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-10 02:50:00.665: E/AndroidRuntime(29564):    at com.appuccino.unitconverter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
10-10 02:50:00.665: E/AndroidRuntime(29564):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
10-10 02:50:00.665: E/AndroidRuntime(29564):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
10-10 02:50:00.665: E/AndroidRuntime(29564):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
10-10 02:50:00.665: E/AndroidRuntime(29564):    ... 11 more
```

And the first part of my mainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        OnItemSelectedListener {

    /**
     * The serialization (saved instance state) Bundle key representing the
     * current dropdown position.
     */
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM = "selected_navigation_item";
    private Spinner firstSpinner;
    private Spinner secondSpinner;
    final String[] mainCategoryChoices = {"Acceleration", "Angles", "Area", "Astronomical", "Clothing", "Computers and Electronics", "Cooking", "Date/Time", "Density", "Energy"};
    final String[] subCategoryChoices = {"Acre", "Barn", "Bunder", "Hundred", "Jerib", "Kappland", "Labor", "Ping", "Rai", "Shed", "Sitio", "Square", "Square Mile", "Square Yard"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);  //not necessary
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayAdapter<String> firstAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                mainCategoryChoices);
    ArrayAdapter<String> secondAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                subCategoryChoices);
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    if(actionBar != null)
    {
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar_custom);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    }

    firstSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.firstSpinner);
    secondSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.secondSpinner);

    firstSpinner.setAdapter(firstAdapter);
    secondSpinner.setAdapter(secondAdapter);

    firstSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    secondSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

}
```

Line 37 that the log info is pointing to goes to the line saying

```
final String[] subCategoryChoices = {"Acre", "Barn", "Bunder", "Hundred", "Jerib", "Kappland", "Labor", "Ping", "Rai", "Shed", "Sitio", "Square", "Square Mile", "Square Yard"};
```

though when I click on it it goes to the line just above the onCreate(), what could be making it crash?

Comment: The LogCat IS pointing at a particular line. It says the Exception is being thrown on line 37.

Comment: Logcat points to `at com.appuccino.unitconverter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)`. There is a NPE there. Show us what line is that and we may provide more accurate help.

Comment: Always look for the `Caused by` line in the stack trace that tells you what and where your error happened

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited the original post and added at the bottom that line 37 is the creation of subCategoryChoices[], though when I double click it it directs me to the line just above onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that the `NPE` is in this line.-

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
```

According to [getWindow()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getWindow%28%29) documentation, chances are that the method will still return `null` inside `onCreate`. If the line is not necessary as the comment states, just try and remove it.

Also, you should double check that your `activity_main` layout contains views `firstSpinner` and `secondSpinner`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the problem with the help of [ssantos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1026645/ssantos) and [zookey's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/955836/zookey) answer, I am using a custom actionBar layout which contains the spinners, and the activity_main is simply a frameLayout used to display fragments, therefore the two spinners don't exist in the layout context that I am using.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you null pointer exception at line 37 :     `secondSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.secondSpinner);`

Sou, you should check that your `layout` contains this `Spinner`.

Comment: Apparently you came to this conclusion by counting lines but surely the OP has `import` statements and a `package` name so line 37 would be down further. Also, this wouldn't cause a `NPE` but could lead to one later on.

Comment: Yeah sorry I made an edit, codeMagic is correct in that it is actually further up as there was import data, it is at the line between the creation of subCategoryChoices and the onCreate()